# Inherited child tables/fields are not generated in migrations

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to model and generate a database with inheritance, using entity framework core 3.0.

I'm following the guide in https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy

Im my code, I have 3 classes: Parent is "Source", and to inherited children "Publication" and "Feeder"

The guide tells that all field from child classes will be in the global table. But they are not.

My model is the following (one parent class, two children)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Legal.Models {
    public enum SourceType { Publication, Feeder }
    // An issuer can have one or more sources. Every source has a type among 3 types


    [Table("Source")]
    public class Source {
        // PK
        public int SourceId { get; set; }
        // Attributes
        public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("Source")]
    public class Publication : Source {
        [MaxLength(13)]
        public string ISSN;
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string IssueTocUrl;

        // Generate FK in Issues
        // public List<Source> Sources { get; } = new List<Source>();
    }

    [Table("Source")]
    public class Feeder : Source {
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string FeederUrl;
    }

}
```

I generate the migration using the following command line

```
dotnet ef migrations add Version_0_0
```

It generates the following designer code (that seems correct - check source, feeder and publication entities)

```
// <auto-generated />
using System;
using Legal.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace Legal.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(LegalDbContext))]
    [Migration("20191022181406_Version_0_0")]
    partial class Version_0_0
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.0.0")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 64);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Legal.Models.Issuer", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("IssuerId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("varchar(64)")
                        .HasMaxLength(64);

                    b.Property<string>("LandPageUrl")
                        .HasColumnType("longtext")
                        .HasMaxLength(2048);

                    b.HasKey("IssuerId");

                    b.ToTable("Issuer");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Legal.Models.Source", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("SourceId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("longtext");

                    b.Property<string>("Discriminator")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("longtext");

                    b.Property<int?>("IssuerId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("SourceType")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("SourceId");

                    b.HasIndex("IssuerId");

                    b.ToTable("Source");

                    b.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator").HasValue("Source");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Legal.Models.Feeder", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Legal.Models.Source");

                    b.ToTable("Source");

                    b.HasDiscriminator().HasValue("Feeder");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Legal.Models.Publication", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Legal.Models.Source");

                    b.ToTable("Source");

                    b.HasDiscriminator().HasValue("Publication");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Legal.Models.Source", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Legal.Models.Issuer", null)
                        .WithMany("Sources")
                        .HasForeignKey("IssuerId");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

But the generation script only include the source table WITHOUT any of the child fields

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Legal.Migrations
{
    public partial class Version_0_0 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Issuer",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    IssuerId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 64, nullable: true),
                    LandPageUrl = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2048, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Issuer", x => x.IssuerId);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Source",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    SourceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    SourceType = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    IssuerId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Source", x => x.SourceId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Source_Issuer_IssuerId",
                        column: x => x.IssuerId,
                        principalTable: "Issuer",
                        principalColumn: "IssuerId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Source_IssuerId",
                table: "Source",
                column: "IssuerId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Source");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Issuer");
        }
    }
}
```

NOTICE: 
I have tried
- With no annotatios
- With data annotations configuring 3 tables (Source, Publication and Feeder)
- With data annotations configuring only 1 table (Source - current example)
- With DbSet per every class
- Overriding OnModelCreating

```
        // Define the table based collections
        public DbSet<Issuer> Issuers { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feeder> Feeders { get; set; }
        // Force creation of child Sources

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Publication>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Feeder>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the same name for all the table attributes: [Table("Source")]

sorry to make it unclear, but this should bring you some informations https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance -> bascially all your tables get generated into the "Source" table and are only separated by the Discriminator flag.

See -> `Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),` in the generated Source Table

Example from the Link, where the Inherited Items are separated by the Discriminator:

[image]

if you give them all different table names like i stated above you can just query them by the table name -> SELECT * FROM Sources WHERE Discriminator = "Source" would give you all data from the "Source" table

with the dbset like you had

```
public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
public DbSet<Feeder> Feeders { get; set; }
```

and you query on them you will get the right items from the database.

just change the `[Table("Source")]` to something useful

Comment: As commented, I have tried with no annotations, same name and different names. In all cases, child tables were not generated.

Comment: Hi, your answer is totally clear, but it doesn' works yet. I have done some progress. I have removed the Annotations, and trying to set the table names in the OnModelCreating. If I try to set the child table names there, I get an exception fully documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#totable-on-a-derived-type-throws-an-exception, so it is reading correctly my try to generate inherited tables. So, now, I have no table names (no annotations neither OnModelCreating). Also, I have tried MySQL and SqlServer (same behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my (stupid) error.

I forgot to declare the setter/getter. The process only generate fields with get/set.

This is the right code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Legal.Models {
    public enum SourceType { Publication, Feeder }
    // An issuer can have one or more sources. Every source has a type among 3 types

    public abstract class Source {
        // PK
        public int SourceId { get; set; }
        // Attributes
        public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1024)]
        public string ServiceClass { get; set; }

        // Parent/Many to One relation shipp
        public int IssuerId { get; set; }
        public Issuer Issuer { get; set; }
    }


    public class Publication : Source {
        [MaxLength(13)]
        public string ISSN { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string IssueTocUrl { get; set; }

        // Generate FK in Issues
        public List<PublicationIssue> PublicationIssues { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feeder : Source {
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string FeederUrl { get; set; }
    }


}
```